# SPARQL insert query not inserting

Tags: rdf, sparql

When I run this SPARQL update:

```
INSERT {
  GRAPH <n4> {
    ?s foaf:firstName ?o
  }
}
WHERE {
  GRAPH <n1> {
    ?s foaf:familyName ?o .
    ?o foaf:familyName ?x
  }
}
```

Although it is syntactically fine, I get no results. Is it because `?s` from the INSERT clause can not be bound to `?s` and `?o` simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

Your query is syntactically fine for SPARQL, but the patterns that it would match probably, in most cases, aren't legal RDF.  In particular, it's unlikely that this pattern:

```
?s foaf:familyName ?o .
?o foaf:familyName ?x
```

will ever match your data.  The value of `?o` is very likely to be a string, which is an RDF literal, and literals cannot be the subjects of triples in RDF, so it's very unlikely that `?o foaf:familyName ?x` can ever match.  Since this means that no triples will match the WHERE part of the query, there's nothing to insert.  I'd suggest that you first run

```
SELECT ?s ?o WHERE {
  GRAPH <n1> {
    ?s foaf:familyName ?o .
    ?o foaf:familyName ?x
  }
}
```

to see what values of `?s` and `?o` would available for the INSERT.  I expect that you won't see any results, and that's why you're not inserting any triples into `n4`.

As to the particular question that you asked,

> Is it because `?s` from the INSERT clause can not be bound to `?s` and `?o` simultaneously?

there's no issue about simultaneous bindings.  The WHERE part of the query produces a (possibly empty) set of results, each of which binds `?s`, `?o`, and `?x`. Then, for each solution, the values of `?s` and `?o` are used to construct the triple `value-of-s foaf:firstName value-of-o` and all of those triples are inserted into `n4`.  Nothing is getting inserted into `n4` because the set of results is empty (for the reasons described above).

Comment: I have triples of the type <iri1> foaf:familyName <iri2> so the above pattern should match. I run the SELECT you proposed and you are right, i get no result but I still cannot explain the why.

Comment: @Cheryl That you have an IRI as a family name seems a bit odd to me, but it's perfectly legal.  However, to match `?s familyName ?o . ?o familyName ?x`, you'd need data of the form `<iri1> familyName <iri2>` _and_ `<iri2> familyName <iri3>`. Does your family name `<iri2>` also have a family name `<iri3>`?  The _entire_ pattern in the WHERE must match, including `?o familyName ?x`, even though the `?x` isn't used in the INSERT part.

Comment: Yes I have <iri1> familyName <iri2>, <iri2>familyName <iri3>, <iri3> familyName <iri4> etc

Comment: @Cheryl Please add some of your data to the question.  If your data actually has `<iri1> familyName <iri2>` and `<iri2> familyName <iri3>` in the graph `<n1>`, then the select query should be retrieving it.  Either the data is not in `<n1>`, or it doesn't have the form that you've described, or both.

Comment: I solve the problem it was due to the implementation of Jena Fuseki. When i create explicitly <n4> it gives me the right results.

Comment: @Cheryl If you've found a solution, can you post it as an answer (and accept it) so that other users who might face the same problem can find it?  Be sure to mention the particular version of Fuseki you're using.  According to section [3.1 Graph Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#graphUpdate) of the SPARQL 1.1 spec, “Non-empty inserts into non-existing graphs will, however, implicitly create those graphs,” so if you've found a case where this doesn't happen, you should also let the Jena developers know. If you're using an old version, however, it's possible that it's been fixed…

Answer (score 1):

I used 0.2.7 edition of Jena Fuseki. I think the problem was that I had to create explicitly the graph  and after that to run the INSERT Update. This works for one graph although, if you want to evaluate the groupgraphpattern to a larger dataset (e.g. n1, n2, n3) it gives you no results.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "evaluate the groupgraphpattern to a larger dataset"?

Comment: And more specifically, do you mean that doing this with, e.g., `where { values ?graph { <n1> <n2> <n3> } graph { ?s name ?o . ?o name ?x } }` doesn't work?